# Enumerate a databinding source, Instances in a custom Config Section

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I have some code that binds a datagrid to the instances in a custom web config section. It works fine, I can edit, add and delete entries to the grid and then enumerate the rows of the grid and save the result to the custom config section.

```
BindingSource Source = new BindingSource();
Source.DataSource = EmailCustomSection.Instances;
grdUDL.DataSource = Source;
```

Now I am in a service enviroment: no grid, no form. I have a test harness that runs the dll defining the service. I want to iterate though the `EmailCustomSection.Instances`. I can see that the count is 3 as it should be, but every attempt I make to get the [i] instance fails. I'm looking for a way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
foreach(var item in EmailCustomSection.Instances)
{
   // do stuff with item
}
```

Comment: even managed to type the item... thanks -- converting from VB to c# and sometimes its just getting the synax right -- i was trying direct casts and all manner of things.